# React, looping through object, displaying list, and grabbing that object when selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit: 
I have made it work by getting the target.value from the list, passing that to **firstComp.js**. Where the onChange method is below, but is this the best practice?

```
 onchange = (e) =>{
    let name= e.target.value
    let currentName= this.state.foodData.map((item)=>{
    if(name==item.name){
      console.log(item)
    }
})
}
```

Im doing stephen griders course on react, and trying to implement what he teaches on a personal project, but I cant wrap my head around it.

I have a list, that is looping through an array of objects. When I pick something from that list, I want it to update the state with that object.

**The Layout..**

*DropDownList.js* = return a drop down list with all the ingredient names in foodData

*DropDownItem* = loops through the foodData, returning an option value for each one.

*foodData*.js = db that looks something like this..

```
let foodData=[
  {"name":"MCT Oil", "brand":"Keppi Keto", "servings":1}
  {"name":"Chunky Peanut Butter", "brand":"Skippy"}
]
```

firstComp.js

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import foodData from './food/foodData.js'
import DropDownList from './DropDownList.js'

class Layout extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      foodData:foodData,
      selectedFood:''
    }
    this.onchange =this.onchange.bind(this)
  }
  onchange = (e) =>{
  console.log(e.target.value)

  }
  render () {
    return (<div className='home'>
        <DropDownList foodData={this.state.foodData} onchange={this.onchange}  />
      </div>)
  }
}
const app = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, app)
```

DropDownList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import DropDownItem from './DropDownItem.js'

const DropDownList = (props) =>{
****let textInput = React.createRef();**** //REFS
const ingredientItems = props.foodData.map((ingredient, i)=>{
  return<DropDownItem key={i} ingredient={ingredient} **ref={textInput}**//REFS />
})
    return(
        <select value={ingredientItems.name} onChange ={ (e) => props.onchange(e)} >
          {ingredientItems}
        </select>
    )
}
export default DropDownList;
```

DropDownItem.js

```
import React from 'react'

const DropDownItem = ({ingredient}) =>{
  const itemName = ingredient.name
    return(<option value={itemName}>{itemName}</option> )
  }
export default DropDownItem;
```

[image]

Comment: Please say what the actual error is; you say you can't wrap your head around it - what is actually going wrong with what you've written?

Comment: I am unable to pass the object. I can pass the event handler and get the target.value only

Comment: You can use refs. Take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html to understand how you can apply a ref to an object in the DOM and then at any time you can get the object for that ref (along with its data, value etc).

Comment: I have read the docs and some youtube tutorial as well. The way this is structured for me is hard to implement. I am passing the prop 2 levels deep for the first time and its confusing. I kept getting errors and I ended up making a mess by trying to turn this functional comp into a class, but then I went back to the original as in OP. I updated the op, only the DropDownList.js,, and added in there what the react docs say, but i get error: _react2.default.createRef is not a function

Comment: I just noticed as I posted this, I added it to the functional component, which Im not supposed to,but where am I supposed to ref this the way this is structured?

Comment: Which state do you want to change here?

Comment: selectedFood in firstComp.js...I basically just have a list, when I change the option in the list( , I want to set the state of selectedFood to that corresponding object

Comment: I just updated the post to get it to work, but it seems hacky I dont know why.. I simply passed the target.value  to the onchange method in firstComp.js Where i just used the comparison property to grab the object...Since Im still learning react, what is the best way, if someone can help with the refs issue I appreciate it, as it exploding my brain right now. I have used refs before, but not in this structure( stephen griders course) where he breaks components into the simplest form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use refs here. You can use some kind of handleChange function in your DropdownList component and send back the value to parent component.

```
const DropDownList = (props) => {
  const handleChange = e => props.onchange( e.target.value );
  const ingredientItems = props.foodData.map((ingredient) =>
    <DropDownItem key={ingredient.name} ingredient={ingredient} /> );

  return (
    <select onChange={handleChange}>
      {ingredientItems}
    </select>
  )
}
```

and in the parent component:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  state = {
    foodData,
    selectedFood: foodData[0]
  };

  onchange = name =>
      this.setState({
          selectedFood: foodData.filter(food => food.name === name)[0]
      });

  render() {
    return (<div className='home'>
      <DropDownList foodData={this.state.foodData} onchange={this.onchange} />
    </div>)
  }
}
```

or without struggling with values and filter, we can use `e.target.options.selectedIndex` as OP finds out him/herself :) This is a cleaner way and works as this (only related parts) :

**DropdownList.js**

```
const handleChange = e => props.onchange( e.target.options.selectedIndex);
```

**Layout.js**

```
onchange = index => this.setState({ selectedFood: foodData[index] });
```

Comment: Thanks, I achieved something similar but with worse looking code :)..This is passing in the name,but not the object. Is there a way to pass the object?  I did it one way ( in the OP up top, just console logged it for now). But is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Not the best way but you can get the desired result like this.

Comment: Yea I got there with a similar method, but your code is much cleaner. I did find another way while looking at all the properties of e.target.. I passed e.target.options.selectedIndex... works as well... I just throught I was missing something fundamental to pass up the whole selected object itself without having to filter / map etc on the parent.

Comment: Yeah, this is a cleaner way to do this. Let me add your good solution to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, seems like some trivial stuff that I am spending hours upon hours fiddling with, I hope Im not learning in the slowest way possible.

Comment: You are welcome and no you are not learning in the slowest way if you are new to this. I am also new and I'm struggling time to time like you for a smallest thing :) This is a self learning phase, the more we struggle the better we learn I think.

Comment: Relatively new , about 3 months. I can make enough sense from other people’s code to tweak and build something (very sloppy code), but when it comes to coding it all from complete scratch with my own logic, I see I know very very little of the basics. It helps to know that Im not alone on getting stuck on what an experienced person might solve within 30 seconds.

Comment: We are on the same ship. I watched lots of videos and followed lots of tutorials but when it comes to write something on your own things are not easy that much :) But after writing your own stuff and stuck somewhere, solve it, you will learn permanently or close to that.